# Automatic selection of gcc compiler optimization using Logistic Regression model

Tags: optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, automation, machine-learning

I'm doing a project based on selection of optimization options for gcc compiler using an algorithm called LRM (Logistic Regression Model) based on this paper... http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5066672 .

In this algorithm, First step is to create a training data out of all the combinations of optimization options available (around 65 now) by compiling and executing the program for each combination. Then later use this data to find best set of optimization options for other codes faster.

Could anyone please help me understand how I'm supposed to store all this data. I was planning on creating a 2D array and then storing the array in a binary file. Is there a better way to do this? Plz help. And how do I proceed on using LRM to find the best set from the training data. Any suggestions would also be welcome.

Thankyou.

Comment: And Im very much aware of the fact that the time taken to create a training data will be a looott.. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 2D array, with one column for each option, and one column for the result (run time of a standard test case).  As there are 65 columns, the options are either on or off, there are 2^65 possible combinations, which equals 36893488147419103232.  Sort it by the result column, and that's the optimal set of options!

I think I'd go with a CSV file....

The number of possible combinations is impractical.  Test to find out if any single flag makes your program faster or slower, then if any two combination of flags work better than the sum of their individual improvements (synergistic effects), then do the same with three flags, and so on.  The options can then be used in those synergistic groups to reduce the number of possible combinations.

But that's a ridiculously large number of combinations of options!